# Why is MyApp Instance not executing on python run

Tags: python, kivy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgY4E.jpg)I'm writing a simple code for executing an application in python kivy module I use Pycharm, the syntax is okay but its returning an error saying:

```
 File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject7\main.py", line 12, in <module>
     TestNas().run()
 TypeError: TestNas() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app'
```

I was expecting it to start the simple Kivy Gui but it did not.

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


def TestNas(app):
    def build(self):
        return Label(Text="Test this app")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestNas().run()
```

Comment: If you are following the [kivy howto](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html) I see two differences: You want a `class` inheriting from `App` (capital `A`) , not a function (which is what `def` creates). In the code you pasted you have a **function** (not a class) called `TestNas` which is expecting an argument (`app`) to run correctly. You are calling that **function** when you wrote `TestNas()`, the function expects an argument... crash!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all TestNas() should be a class and I'm guessing it needs to be a subclass of App() that you imported. So change TestNas() to a class and capitalize App().

I think this is the code you need:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class TestNas(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(Text="Test this app")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestNas().run()
```